# Xls to csv - Numbers creates multiple csv files for some reason

Tags: numbers, file-conversion, csv

I have a small xls file which 200Kb of size. When I export it to csv format, Numbers creates multiple csv files. How do I make it create a single one?

Comment: Does it have multiple sheets ?

Answer (score 1):

CSV are simple text file where the data are only separated by comas and new lines.

There is no concept of sheets therefore Numbers need to create a csv for each sheet.